# pymysql-How to add cases on my code

Tags: python, pymysql

So I am trying to get some cases to work on my code but I get all the time the same error TypeError("'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'",).
Can somebody help me?
The code is this:

```
try:
    float(rank1)
except ValueError:
    return [("status",),("error",),]
try:
    float(rank2)
except ValueError:
    return [("status",),("error",),]
if (rank1>=0 and rank1<=10 and rank2>=0 and rank2<=10):
    sql_query='''update movie set rank=(%s + %s)/2 
    where movie.title=%s'''
    cur.execute(sql_query,(rank1,rank2,movieTitle))
    con.commit()
    return [("ok",)]
else :
    return [("status",),("error",),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you probably want is:

```
try: 
    rank1 = float(rank1) 
except ValueError: 
    return [("status",),("error",),] 
try: 
    rank2 = float(rank2) 
except ValueError: 
    return [("status",),("error",),] 

if (rank1>=0 and rank1<=10 and rank2>=0 and rank2<=10):
    sql_query='''update movie set rank=(%s + %s)/2 where movie.title=%s'''
    cur.execute(sql_query,(rank1,rank2,movieTitle)) 
    con.commit() 
    return [("ok",)] 
else: 
    return [("status",),("error",),]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly what it says.

`rank1` is a string.

This excerpt of code doesn't do what you think it does:

```
try:
    float(rank1)
except ValueError:
    return [("status",),("error",),]
```

This does not actually change the value of `rank1` to a float. You need to set this equal to a variable in order to store the new float variable `rank1`.

You can just do `rank1 = float(rank1)` to accomplish this.

Comment: I have one more question I will edit my post so you can see.